Deshabilitar días de la semana en un input type datepicker en filament y laravel
Tengo este codigo en un formulario de filamentphp y estoy buscando la forma de hacer que al seleccionar un valor del select me traiga los dias disponibles de la semana y que al dar click a fecha solo me muestre y me deje dar click a los dias de la semana que esta disponible para solicitar... los días disponibles ya los traigo pero me falta lograr deshabilitar estos días que no vienen en el array en el input type datepicker... este es mi codigo:
Forms\Components\Select::make('common_area_id')
     ->label('Tipo de área')
     ->required()
     ->relationship('commonareas', 'nombre')
     ->reactive()
     ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, callable $get, callable $set) {
        $commonArea = CommonArea::find($state);
     if ($commonArea) {
        $set('valor', $commonArea->valor);
        $set('tramoreserva', "{$commonArea->rangefrom} - {$commonArea->rangeuntil}");
        $set('availabledays', $commonArea->availabledays);
     // Mostrar días disponibles
     //dd($commonArea->availabledays);
     } else {
        $set('valor', '');
        $set('tramoreserva', '');
        $set('availabledays', []);
       }
    }),

en esta primera sección selecciono un valor del modelo y me carga perfecto, de hecho me actualiza de forma dinamica los otros campos en valor y tramo, pero como dije, la idea que busco es que al abrir el input de fecha
Forms\Components\Hidden::make('availabledays')
    ->reactive(),
Forms\Components\DatePicker::make('fecha')
    ->label('Fecha')
    ->minDate(now()->toDateString()) // Fecha mínima de solicitud la actual o mayor
    ->required()
    ->reactive()
    ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, callable $get, callable $set) {
        $commonArea = CommonArea::find($get('common_area_id'));
        if ($commonArea && !empty($commonArea->availabledays)) {
            $set('availabledays', $commonArea->availabledays);
        } else {
          $set('availabledays', []);
        }
      })
    ->disabledDates(function (callable $get) {
        $availableDays = $get('availabledays');
      if (!$availableDays) {
          return [];
      }
   // Mapeo de los días de la semana a sus índices correspondientes
      $dayMap = [
        'Domingo'   => 0,
        'Lunes'     => 1,
        'Martes'    => 2,
        'Miercoles' => 3,
        'Jueves'    => 4,
        'Viernes'   => 5,
        'Sabado'    => 6,
      ];
   // Convertimos los días disponibles a sus índices correspondientes
        $allowedDays = array_map(fn($day) => $dayMap[$day] ?? null, $availableDays);
   // Filtramos los valores nulos por si algún día no coincide
        $allowedDays = array_filter($allowedDays, fn($day) => $day !== null);
   // Los días no permitidos son todos los días de la semana excepto los permitidos
        $unavailableDays = array_diff([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], $allowedDays);
   // Devuelve una función para desactivar los días no permitidos
        return function (\Carbon\Carbon $date) use ($unavailableDays) {
          return in_array($date->dayOfWeek, $unavailableDays);
        };
   }),

que al abrir el input de fecha me desaparezcan deshabilitados los dias que no vienen desde el array en la tabla!
en la columna availabledays tengo estos valores
["Lunes"]
["Sabado","Lunes","Jueves","Miercoles"]
["Miercoles","Lunes","Viernes","Sabado","Martes","Jueves","Domingo"]
para el id 1 Lunes
para el id 2 Sabado, lunes, jueves, miercoles
etc, etc...
que si estos dias no estan en el array se deshabiliten en mi opcion de seleccionar una fecha en el input

Bueno he encontrado una solución, entre ellos agregando native(false) al datepicker y ademas iniciar la semana en dia 1 junto con otros cambios en el codigo para poder trabajar con las condiciones dentro de un rango de meses como maximo desde la fecha actual a 3 meses más...
Forms\Components\DatePicker::make('fecha')
                    ->label('Fecha')
                    ->minDate(now()->toDateString()) // Fecha mínima de solicitud la actual o mayor
                    ->required()
                    ->reactive()
                    ->native(false)
                    ->firstDayOfWeek(1)
                    ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, callable $get, callable $set) {
                        $commonArea = CommonArea::find($get('common_area_id'));
                        if ($commonArea && !empty($commonArea->availabledays)) {
                            $set('availabledays', $commonArea->availabledays);
                        } else {
                            $set('availabledays', []);
                        }
                    })
                    ->disabledDates(function (callable $get) {
                        $availableDays = $get('availabledays');
                        if (!$availableDays) {
                            return [];
                        }

                        $dayMap = [
                            'Lunes'     => 1,
                            'Martes'    => 2,
                            'Miercoles' => 3,
                            'Jueves'    => 4,
                            'Viernes'   => 5,
                            'Sabado'    => 6,
                            'Domingo'   => 7,
                        ];

                        $allowedDays = array_map(fn($day) => $dayMap[$day] ?? null, $availableDays);
                        $allowedDays = array_filter($allowedDays, fn($day) => $day !== null);
                        $unavailableDays = array_diff([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], $allowedDays);

                        $disabledDates = [];
                        $start = Carbon::now();
                        $end = $start->copy()->addMonths(3); // Ejemplo de rango de 3 meses

                        while ($start->lessThanOrEqualTo($end)) {
                            if (in_array($start->dayOfWeek, $unavailableDays)) {
                                $disabledDates[] = $start->format('Y-m-d');
                            }
                            $start->addDay();
                        }

                        return $disabledDates; // Devuelve un array de fechas deshabilitadas
                    }),

